# For two natural numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For any two natural numbers $m$ and $n$, prove that $m^3+n^3+4$ cannot be a perfect cube.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the equation $m^3+n^3+4=k^3$ modulo $9$. A sum of three cubes of integers is never equivalent to $\pm 4$ modulo $9$. For integers a well-known conjecture is that
$x^3+y^3+z^3=n$ with $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ has a solution if and only if $n\not\equiv \pm 4\bmod 9$.

Comment: why is it so can you prove

Comment: What can a cube $n^3$ be modulo $9$ ? Try it: $n=1,2,3,\ldots ,$.

Comment: Cubes  are $\equiv 0,1,8\pmod 9$. For example, because $(n+3)^3\equiv n^3\pmod 9$.

Comment: ok i understand